# EDITED: How to pass a variable from a anchor link to a div

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass a variable from an anchor link and display it in a div on a form so I can post the variable. This is my anchor:

```
if($Count2 == 0) {
echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td align='left' class='roomviewred'>
<span class='roomName'>
<div class='show_login'><a href='#Record?<?php echo $RoomNo2; ?>'></a>$RoomNo2</div>
</span>
<span class='auditMonth2'>$AuditMonth</span>
</td>";
} 
$Count2 = 0;
echo "</tr>
```

The Form:

```
<div class = "loginform">
<form method = "post" action = "clear_faults_submit.php" target="_self">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ButtonText"></td>
<td><input type = "password" id = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "***"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><div id="Record"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="center"><input type = "image" id = "dologin" src = "images/login.png"></td>
<td width="50%" align="center"><input type = "image" id = "close_login" src = "images/cancel.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".show_login").click(function(){
  showpopup();
 });
 $(".close_login").click(function(){
  $('.show_login').hide();
 });
});

function showpopup()
{
 $(".loginform").fadeIn();
 $(".loginform").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
}

function hidepopup()
{
 $(".loginform").fadeOut();
 $(".loginform").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
}
```

I have spent hours trying differnt methods and from what I have read, the above code should work. It does not, so I must be doing something wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

This is the way I resolved my question.

**EDITED**

This is how I solved my question. For my link code I now have:

```
<div class="show_login"><a  href="#<?php echo $RoomNo2;?>" class="testClick"><span class="RommDisplay"><?php echo $RoomNo2;?></span></a></div>
```

I added a class named "Click", "class="Click"". When the link is clicked the class="Click" is captured by the following JQuery function and produces a 
variable call "anchorValue" and assigns the resulf to another variable called "room". I then use "room" to get the data into an document.getElementById which
I can use in my popup form. This may not be the most elegant or tidy way, but it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".Click").click(function () {
    var anchorValue= $(this).attr("href");
    var room = (anchorValue[0] == '#') ? anchorValue.substr(1) : anchorValue;

 $(".show_login").click(function(){
 document.getElementById('Record').innerHTML=room;
 document.getElementById('Room').innerHTML=room;
  showpopup();
 });
 $(".close_login").click(function(){
  $('.show_login').hide();
 });
});

function showpopup()
{
 $(".loginform").fadeIn();
 $(".loginform").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
}

function hidepopup()
{
 $(".loginform").fadeOut();
 $(".loginform").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
}
});
```

And in my popup FORM I have which hold the value of the :

```
<input type="hidden" id="Room" name="Room" /><div id="Record"></div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? and who told you that that code should work?

Comment: Need more clarification or show the whole code here

Comment: So you need `$RoomNo2` inside the div `Record`, or some where else? Its not clear. Normal we can pass variable in url like `<a href="url.php?link=<?=$a?> '>Link 1</a>` and take it as `$_GET['link']`

Comment: "display it in a div on a form so I can post the variable."...divs do not get posted back. You'd have to put it in a form element (e.g. in a hidden field as well as a div is one option).

Comment: Anyway I can't see how your code would do anything useful. You'll end up with a href something like `#Record?1` which makes no sense. Your parameters need names. And The "Record" div is static and won't contain anything unless you actually write some code to do that.

Comment: You cant echo in echo. remove php open and close and echo near $RoomNo2

Answer (score 2):

This is get request.

so in your link give name to your request.
`<div class='show_login'><a href='#Record?variable=<?php echo $RoomNo2; ?>'></a>$RoomNo2</div>` now we can get value with $_GET['variable']

inside your #Record

```
<div id="Record">
   <?php isset($_GET['variable']) ? $_GET['variable'] : '' ?>
</div>
```

this was short if else statemanet. Remeber always check variable if exist write it to screen else it will throw error that undefined

Comment: Zarbaliyev Hi and thanks for your reply. I changed my code to yours but the <div id="Record"></div> is empty. Looking at the code in Firefox Inspector I can see the HREF and it does contain the correct data, in this test case it displays "<div class="show_login"><a href="#Record?variable=<?php echo 103; ?>"></a>103</div>" and the div displays "<div id="Record"></div>". Any ideas?

Comment: @DCJones re your output of `variable=<?php echo 103; ?>` ...judging by the (recently edited) code above you're already within a string being output by an echo statement at this point, so you just need to include the $RoomNo2 variable, you can't echo within an echo. e.g. `variable=$RoomNo2`. I believe this answer was posted before you added that information, so understandably it didn't know the context.

Comment: @ADyson Hi, I am not completely understanding you comment, "you can't echo within an echo". Are you referring to this line of code "<div class='show_login'><a href='#Record?variable=<?php echo $RoomNo2; ?>'></a>$RoomNo2</div>". Again many thanks for your time.

Comment: @DCJones Look at your code: `echo "<td align='left' class='roomviewred'>
<span class='roomName'>
<div class='show_login'><a href='#Record?<?php echo $RoomNo2; ?>'></a>$RoomNo2</div>
</span>
<span class='auditMonth2'>$AuditMonth</span>
</td>";` you have echo within a string which is already in a echo statement. Makes no sense at all. That inner echo is just treated the same as any other piece of text within the string, it is not interpreted as a PHP command.

Comment: @DCJones doing simply `echo "<td align='left' class='roomviewred'> <span class='roomName'> <div class='show_login'><a href='#Record?$RoomNo2'></a>$RoomNo2</div> </span> <span class='auditMonth2'>$AuditMonth</span> </td>";` will solve it (putting the variable in there works because PHP automatically interpolates variables placed within a double-quoted string and echoes their value, which you already know because you've done it elsewhere in that same line of code).

Comment: Hi all, thank you to all the people who helped with my question. I now have it working using the code which I have put in my original question. I hope it helps someone.